# Is it possible to use many image slices to achieve `background-size: cover` effect?

Tags: css

If I use `background-size: cover;` with a single large image file, I get the effect I want. But if I create the background using *image slicing* technique (i.e. divide the image into several images and compress the images differently to achieve better file size reductions), could the same effect be achieved somehow?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question properly. It sounds like you’ve got one image that you want to cover the entire background of the element (regardless of how big the element gets), but you want to split that image up into several images, so that you’ve got several smaller images instead of one bigger one. Won’t the smaller images be the same size in total as the one big image?

Comment: I can compress the slices differently (.jpg, .png or so) depending on the particular slice, and therefore, I could get the sum of slices smaller than if using a single large image file.

Comment: I think you should load one only image and apply different compression in different areas. I think some software is able to do so (e.g. you could posterize a selection) and you would need only one get instead of `<n>`

Comment: I'd also need one image slice to be .png (or the whole single image) because I need one transparent area.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan, nice idea, do you know any software that could apply different compression on different areas for a .png image?

Answer (score 0):

[`background-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) can take percentage values, and you have different `background-size` and background-position` values for different background images (separated by commas), so you might be able to get it to work.

However, because of the way `background-position` works, it might be a bit tricky — `background-position: 50% 0;` means “position the image so that the point 50% of the way along the images’s length is 50% of the way along the element’s length”. For complicated slices, it might take a lot of fiddling to get the images to line up, and there could be 1-pixel rounding issues.

**Edit:** and, as you’ve pointed out in the comments, `background-size:cover` maintains the image’s width/height ratio whilst ensuring that the background is covered, which the percentage values can’t unless you know the dimensions of the element in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think using percentage values doesn't solve the problem with scaling the slices. [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/) says in the background-size 'cover' section: **Scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio (if any), to the smallest size such that both its width and its height can completely cover the background positioning area.**

Comment: @anssi: ah, that’s a very good point — yup, you definitely couldn’t achieve that effect with multiple background images.